# How I (simply) Forward All Incoming Email to an External Address (ie. Gmail)?

Tags: centos, postfix, sendmail, mail-forwarding

With Google Apps no longer being free for small businesses/teams, I'm left pointing my MX records at my application server. I'd still like to receive email at a Gmail address sent to the domain associated with aforementioned MX records.

I have looked at installing sendmail and configuring `/etc/mail/virtusertable` to contain something like

```
@mydomain    myemail@gmail.com
```

I have also looked at installing postfix and modifying `/etc/aliases` with

```
admin:  myemail@gmail.com
team:  myemail@gmail.com
...
```

Regardless, when I send email to `team@mydomain.com` the emails never seem to make it to my application server (for example, `/var/log/maillog` shows nothing added), and definitely don't make it back to my Gmail account.

I am fine discarding postfix and/or sendmail for another alternative; I'm simply looking to accept email on my application server that does nothing but forward said email to a Gmail account. I don't need/want any real email accounts on the server, and this is the only domain on the server.

Comment: If you want to redirect email to different domains on per-address basis, try using transport tables. http://serverfault.com/a/184228/23300

Comment: How many users do you plan on having?  Are you sure this solution is going to be cheaper (and more reliable) than the $50 per user per year that Google Apps now costs?

Answer (score 1):

With sendmail you need to add something like this at the end of you `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
Kuser user -m -a.FOUND

LOCAL_RULE_0
R$- < @ $=w . > $*        $: $(user $1 $) < @ $2 . > $3
R$- . FOUND < @ $=w . > $*          $@ username < @ gmail.com. > $3
```

That would forward any email directed to a user of the system (listed in `/etc/passwd`) to your username@gmail.com.  Keep in mind that the left hand side of the rules is separated from the right hand side of the rules with tabs and not spaces. So do not copy paste, type the above rules instead.  After that you need to run `/etc/mail/make` to build `sendmail.cf` and `service sendmail restart` in order for the changes to take place.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you need to get a working installation of postfix or sendmail on your server which is a real pain in the ass. Relaying email on postfix once you get it up and running however is a straight forward process.

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-relay-email-on-a-postfix-server

I'm actually running a postfix/dovecot server that is doing exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing appears in you postfix logs, it looks like you're server doesn't get the incoming connection, because it doesn't feel responsible for the domain you want to send the mail to.

Virtual User and Domain tables are a good start, but make sure postfix feels responsible with adding the domain to "mydestination" like this:

```
mydestination = localhost, mydomain.tld, mail.mydomain.tld
```

Don't forget to hash it first:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtusertable
```

Include your virtusertable in the alias maps:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtusertable
```

and last but not least, check that postfix is actually getting the request

```
dig mydomain.tld MX
```

and your domain and check for the MX records, that they  point to the postfix server.
If you just changed it today / MX DNS entries, it could take up to 24hours before the changes become visible because of DNS caching at your DNS, yours provider DNS or other DNS servers of servers which send mail to mydomain.tld

Answer (score 0):

With sendmail you may add something like this to your /etc/mail/sendmail.mc:

```
define(`LUSER_RELAY',`error:550 User unknown')
define(`MAIL_HUB',`esmtp:username@gmail.com')
```

It should reject emails to unknown local users after (LUSER_RELAY) and send messages to remaining local email address to username@gmail.com (MAIL_HUB).
It is applied after alias expansion and ~/.forward file processing.

**WARNINGS:**

- The method will not handle well rejects by destination email e.g. caused by antispam procedure.
- **DO NOT** use the recipe with `FEATURE(stickyhost)`
- I post it mainly as an alternative to custom `R` lines based solutions.